# How to shutdown MySQL server from java

Tags: java, mariadb

I'm using a portable MariaDB (10.3.31) for a program written in Java.

When the program starts the database server starts like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + "\\database\\bin\\mysqld.exe --port=15001");
```

So far so good. The server starts with no problem.

But I'm not able to shutdown the database server:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + "\\database\\bin\\mysqladmin --port=15001 -u root -p shutdown");
```

By the way, I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: You might have to run that as an administrator

Comment: Did you already try to shutdown the server with same command from command prompt?

Comment: @GeorgRichter when I try that the cmd asks for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shutdown command should be like this:

```
mysqladmin --port=15001 -u root shutdown
```

I've removed `-p` because I'm using the default credentials which doesn't require a password.

Answer (score 0):

You need either pass the password directly to mysqladmin command, or you have to connect to the database server and execute the SQL command `SHUTDOWN` to shutdown the server.

Executing SHUTDOWN command requires that shutdown privileges have been granted to the connected user.

Comment: There's no password in my database. I'm using the default credentials. However your answer and comment have indirectly helped me to find the correct solution.

Comment: If there is no password you shouldn't specify -p option in mysqladmin, since -p without password forces command line tools to ask for a password.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so.

There are no SQL command for shutting down MySQL (and
obviously none to start it).

`Runtime.exec` seems as the only way.

Comment: See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/shutdown/